# Remove leading zeros from IP Address with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address

I have an IP like this "127.000.000.001" how can I remove the leading zeros to get this "127.0.0.1"?
For now i use regex like this

```
Regex.Replace("127.000.000.001", "0*([0-9]+)", "${1}")
```

Is there any other way to achieve this result without using regex?

I use visual C# 3.0 for this code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's a much better way than using regular expressions for this.

Instead, try the [`System.Net.IpAddress` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx).

There is a [`ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tostring.aspx) that will return a human-readable version of the IP address in its standard notation. This is probably what you want here.

Comment: I'm concerned with Brent's answer. I have the problem with IPAddress.Parse. leading zeroes interpret as Octal. so how ToString is going to help since it needs an IPAddress first and that to make one from a string you need to Parse first. unfortunately, that is where this answer fails.

Comment: This will be false in case IP = 172.016.000.000. After calling IPAddress.Parse(IP), the result will be 172.14.0.0. It is incorrect. We should remove the leading 0 of the ip address.

Comment: So there is a bug in the `IPAddress.Parse` method, @Phuc? Is that what you're saying? Have you filed a bug report with Microsoft? What happens when you use [the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx)? Do you see the same behavior?

Comment: This is treated as octal. If I remember right, I saw this with constructor too. IpAddress really needs a ParseExact. See below answers.

Comment: @CodyGray, I think before we use IPAddress.Parse(), we should remove the leading zero in the ipaddress string. And then, the returned result from IPAddress.Parse() will always correct.

Answer (score 14):

The IP Address object will treat a leading zero as octal, so it should not be used to remove the leading zeros as it will not handle 192.168.090.009.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/21510004-b719-410e-bbc5-a022c40a8369

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Brent, `IPAddress.TryParse` treats leading zeros as octal and will result in a bad answer.  One way of fixing this issue is to use a [`RegEx.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the replacement.  I personally like this one that looks for a 0 followed by any amount of numbers.

```
Regex.Replace("010.001.100.001", "0*([0-9]+)", "${1}")
```

It will return `10.1.100.1`. This will work only if the entire text is an IP Address.

Comment: "Is there any other way to achieve this result without using regex?"
You have made no attempt to solve the asker's problem. In fact, you have answered with how they are currently solving the problem. They asked for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

don't need regex to do that, you can do something like this.

```
IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.000.000.001");
IP.ToString()
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use below logic writien in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int inlen=strlen(argv[1])+1, cnt=0, dstcnt=0;
    char dststr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]="";

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("usage: ipvalidator [ip]\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for(cnt=0; cnt<inlen; cnt++)
    {
        if(argv[1][cnt]=='\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        
        if( (argv[1][cnt]=='0') && (argv[1][cnt+1] == '0') &&
            ((cnt==0) ||(argv[1][cnt-1] == '.') || (argv[1][cnt-1] == '0')) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        if( (argv[1][cnt]=='0') && (argv[1][cnt+1] >= '1') && 
            (argv[1][cnt+1] <= '9') && 
            ((cnt==0) || (argv[1][cnt-1] == '.') || (argv[1][cnt-1] == '0')) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        dststr[dstcnt++] = argv[1][cnt];

    }
    dststr[dstcnt++] = '\0';

    printf("New IP String: %s\n",dststr);
    return dstcnt;
}
```

Comment: The tag specifically say C# yet this is a C code. At the very least convert it to C# to make it an answer