# Why do I get different results from the C# System.Net.IPAddress.Parse() method when including a leading zero in my IPAddress string?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I was working with some simple server client socket code in a Godot 3 application.  For some reason, when I use this code:

`IPAddress ipa = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("131.236.053.199");`

and print the result to the console via `Console.WriteLine(ipa.ToString());` I get:

131.236.43.199

If I remove the leading zero from the 3rd byte and execute this line:

`IPAddress ipa = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("131.236.53.199");`

and print the result via `Console.WriteLine(ipa.ToString());` I get the desired address:

and print the result to the console I get:

131.236.53.199

Is there a reason why does the leading zero makes a difference?  Is this a bug in the Microsoft code or am I missing something else?

I've read the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx and couldn't see why this behaviour would occur.

Thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/857618/52365

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863545/780798

Comment: Thank you for the links.  Although those questions are different, the explanation there of leading zeroes signalling a number as octal rather than decimal is likely the explanation for the behaviour I observed.

Comment: If you check source code of the IPAddress parse method, it uses [ParseNonCanonical](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/_IPv4Address.cs,bfef6214a87144d6,references) method. And there you can see i on line 184 that when 0 is detected parser switched to octal number base. So when you think you using 053 as decimal it is actually 53 as octal number. Open calculator in programmer mode and enter 53 in OCT - you will get 43 as decimal.